# Any project hosting with a in-browser code editor like Google Code?

Tags: git, mercurial, hosting, dvcs

[Google Code Project Hosting](http://code.google.com/hosting/) recently adapted CodeMirror to allow for [quick in-browser editing of code in a repository](http://google-opensource.blogspot.com/2011/01/make-quick-fixes-quicker-on-google.html). This seems extremely useful! Unfortunately not all of my projects are open source.

Are there any other DVCS (Mercurial or Git) hosts that also have this feature but support closed-source projects? In particular, free would be nice (since I'd like to host personal projects with it and be able to tweak them in the browser); I'm a student, so if there's a discount or free mode due to that, that's cool too!

Comment: As an aside the primary drawback of edit-on-web is that it pretty much guarantees you have code in the repository that hasn't passed your test suite.  For some projects that doesn't matter at all, but for others it represents a real drop in quality control.

Comment: Do you know if there is one for an in-house solution, Open Source?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

GitHub can do that. There is a “edit this file” button next to each code viewer.

See also the “Edit Online” section on [Features / Hosting](https://github.com/features/hosting).

#### Update (May 2013)

Bitbucket [recently introduced](http://blog.bitbucket.org/2013/05/14/edit-your-code-in-the-cloud-with-bitbucket/) a online code editor, just like the one GitHub provides. As Bitbucket also offers free private repositories (up to 5 collaborators) this is definitely a good alternative to GitHub.

Comment: But you have to pay to host *closed-source* projects…

Comment: @Simon: The question doesn't mention anywhere that the OP is looking for a *free* service...

Comment: Looks like he edited his question to say he prefers free.

Answer (score 5):

GitLab version 3.0+ has a web editor now.
Follow the installation instruction here.
https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/stable/doc/installation.md

If the feature does not work, check this one as well.
https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/1761

Answer (score 2):

I'm looking for the same thing. So far I've found only the combination of  http://c9.io/  (cloud9 ide) and bitbucket (both of them offer free accounts). I haven't tried it yet:

http://blog.bitbucket.org/2011/06/07/cloud9-ide-now-integrates-with-bitbucket/

kodingen.com looks very promising as well but at the time of this writing is in beta and the DVCS are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

At long last [Bitbucket](http://www.bitbucket.org/) can now also be used for online editing for both public as well as private repositories (free and paid both).

Answer (score -2):

Check out http://bitbucket.org for Mercurial.

Comment: I don't see any edit button in Bitbucket... Am I missing something?

Comment: bitbucket is awesome, but surely doesn't have an edit online feature (yet!)

Comment: My bad, I parsed "editing" as "viewing."